# not able to apply custom function in polars

Tags: python, dataframe, python-polars

I have a custom function previously working pretty fine in Pandas, but somehow it won't work in the polars apply() function when I am trying to migrate to polars.

below is my code.

```
df = df.sort("time", descending=False)
latest_day = df[-1,'time']
def fetch_price(self, date): # the custom function
    if date <= latest_day:
        return df[date,self.name]
    else:
        return None
```

```
def get_rate(self, direction, margin, test_cycle):
    # retrieve relevant data from df
    self.df = (df[['time', self.name]].drop_nulls())[
              test_cycle * -1:]  # test_cycle*-1. test_cycle大于life_cycle。
    # apply next_trade_day to 'time' column, and create a new column 'Maturity_Date'
    self.df = self.df.with_columns(
        (pl.col('time').apply(lambda x: next_trade_day(x, self.life_cycle))).alias('Maturity_Date'))
    # check if the generated dates are in the original time series
    self.df = self.df.with_columns(pl.col('Maturity_Date').is_in(df['time']).cast(bool).alias('Data_Accessibility'))
    # maturity price on the day of maturity
    # apply fetch_price to 'Maturity_Date' column if 'Data_Accessibility' is True, and create a new column 'Maturity_Price'
    # self.df = self.df.with_columns((pl.col('Maturity_Date').apply(lambda x: self.fetch_price(x))).alias('Maturity_Price'))
    self.df = self.df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('Maturity_Date') <= pl.col('time').last()).then(pl.col(self.name)).alias('Maturity_Price'))
    print(self.df)

CU = future('CU8888.SHF', 33)
CU.get_rate(1, 0.05, 8000)
```

This is the output of `print (self.df)` :

```
┌────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ time       ┆ CU8888.SHF ┆ Maturity_Date ┆ Data_Accessibility │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ date       ┆ f64        ┆ date          ┆ bool               │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ …          ┆ …          ┆ …             ┆ …                  │
│ 2023-03-23 ┆ 68274.0    ┆ 2023-04-25    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-24 ┆ 69670.0    ┆ 2023-04-26    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-27 ┆ 69161.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-28 ┆ 69244.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              │
└────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┘
```

Comment: You're using `df.loc` inside `fetch_price` - there is no `.loc` in polars.

Comment: @jqurious thanks.fixed the grammar now, but still getting exactly the same error...

Comment: Can you give us a code example that we can run?

Comment: I would like to , but am not quite sure how? the script also comes with an excel file to run with.

Comment: The error says `fetch_price` is the problem. `df[date][self.name]` looks suspect, what is that supposed to do? As for an example we can run, you're using the `time` column in the apply. Can you reproduce the error if you only call `df.limit(5).with_columns((pl.col('time').apply(...))` on its own, without this `get_rate` function? - if so, you could provide `df.limit(5).get_column("time")` as your example, along with `self.name` and `latest_day`

Comment: yes I can reproduce the error with `df.limit(5).with_columns((pl.col('time').apply(...))` and I have uploaded the output of `df.limit(5).get_column("time")` above

Comment: the column 'Maturity_Date' is a new time series calculated based on a given future's life cycle. the function of fetch_price is to find the historical price accordingly back in the original time series.

Comment: The previous edit showing all the columns was actually better, if you can also show what the  `latest_day` and `self.name` values are, that helps.

Comment: okk I have uploaded the table back. latest_day is a constant as the line `latest_day = df['time'][-1]` above I have just added now, basically the day when we recently updated our future data.

Comment: Is there any more info in your traceback? There should be some initial errors prior to the final `PanicException` you were getting.

Comment: ahh, yes. it goes`thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'python function failed ValueError: Cannot __getitem__ on DataFrame with item: '2004-01-02' of type: '<class 'datetime.date'>'.', src/apply/series.rs:219:19
note: run with RUST_BACKTRACE=1 environment variable to display a backtrace
--- PyO3 is resuming a panic after fetching a PanicException from Python. ---
Python stack trace below:`

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/expr/expr.py", line 3345, in wrap_f
    return x.apply(
           ^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/polars/series/series.py", line 4034, in apply
    self._s.apply_lambda(function, pl_return_dtype, skip_nulls)`

Comment: Ok so, `df[date, ...]` is the problem. I guess you had a dateindex in pandas. It looks like you could replace the whole apply thing with: `df.with_columns(pl.when(pl.col('time') <= pl.col('time').last()).then(pl.col(self.name)).alias('Maturity_Price'))`

Comment: hmmm, thanks for the tip, but there is something very strange happening when I try this... the maturity_price column has the exactly same values as the CU8888.SHF column's.

Comment: and I have noticed something stranger: previously when I called `df = df.sort("time", descending=False)`,the date 2004-01-02 has then been duplicated several times, the dates are originally unique.

Comment: Your comment says `apply fetch_price to 'Maturity_Date' column` but you are applying it to the `time` column. Should it be `pl.col('Maturity_Date')` instead?

Comment: yes you are right, I have fixed this typo haha. but still getting the same values.

Comment: Okay. So what should the values be for the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue here was you had a datetime index in pandas and could use `df.loc[date, ...]` to do a "row lookup".

There is no `.loc` or indexes in polars, however, the `.apply` + `.loc` approach being used is essentially mimicking the functionality of a [*left join*](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/howcani/combining_data/joining.html#left-join).

```
df = pl.from_repr("""
┌────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┐
│ time       ┆ CU8888.SHF ┆ Maturity_Date ┆ Data_Accessibility │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---                │
│ date       ┆ f64        ┆ date          ┆ bool               │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╡
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               │
│ 2004-02-04 ┆ 99999.0    ┆ 2004-05-10    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-23 ┆ 68274.0    ┆ 2023-04-25    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-24 ┆ 69670.0    ┆ 2023-04-26    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-27 ┆ 69161.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              │
│ 2023-03-28 ┆ 69244.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              │
└────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┘
""")
```

```
df.join(
   df.select("time", Maturity_Price = "CU8888.SHF"), 
   left_on="Maturity_Date", 
   right_on="time", 
   how="left"
)
```

```
shape: (9, 5)
┌────────────┬────────────┬───────────────┬────────────────────┬────────────────┐
│ time       ┆ CU8888.SHF ┆ Maturity_Date ┆ Data_Accessibility ┆ Maturity_Price │
│ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---           ┆ ---                ┆ ---            │
│ date       ┆ f64        ┆ date          ┆ bool               ┆ f64            │
╞════════════╪════════════╪═══════════════╪════════════════════╪════════════════╡
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               ┆ 99999.0        │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               ┆ 99999.0        │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               ┆ 99999.0        │
│ 2004-01-02 ┆ 23275.0    ┆ 2004-02-04    ┆ true               ┆ 99999.0        │
│ …          ┆ …          ┆ …             ┆ …                  ┆ …              │
│ 2023-03-23 ┆ 68274.0    ┆ 2023-04-25    ┆ false              ┆ null           │
│ 2023-03-24 ┆ 69670.0    ┆ 2023-04-26    ┆ false              ┆ null           │
│ 2023-03-27 ┆ 69161.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              ┆ null           │
│ 2023-03-28 ┆ 69244.0    ┆ 2023-05-04    ┆ false              ┆ null           │
└────────────┴────────────┴───────────────┴────────────────────┴────────────────┘
```

Comment: thanks bro.. but this is not what I wanted, I was trying to find say, take the first row for example, the price on 2004-02-04 in column 'CU8888.SHF' (which is 25730.0 in my excel), and would like to put it into the column Maturity_Price. column 'time' used to be my index in pandas,  and historical prices are registered according to this time series.

Comment: Okay, so you need to find the value from the corresponding row where `pl.col("time") == pl.col("Maturity_Date")`?

Comment: yes, that's exactly what I wanted, not quite sure how to express properly though. would polars interpret that I would like the two columns to have identical dates?

Comment: That's essentially a `.join` operation.

Comment: hahah, thanks so much for bearing with me mate, I'll have a look at the .join document.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show the left join. `CU8888.SHF_right` would be the `Maturity_Price` column - I added in an extra row to the sample dataframe because there were no matches in the original example.

Comment: Generally, with polars, using `.apply` is an "anti-pattern". You can probably replace the `next_trade_day` one also, depending on what it does. Using either polars expressions, or like in this case, some other functionality.

Comment: I see. I shall give it a try. just one more question though, could we rename the auto-generated `CU8888.SHF_right` column as `Maturity Price` within the join function?

Comment: You can choose the name in the `.select`